# google maps marker load via ajax and infocontent

Tags: django, google-maps

In my app I have a google map and I want to add many marker on it and so I load the data via ajax (I'm in Django). I have the probem with infocontent and the 'click' event on the marker load via ajax:  When I do 'click' on the marker nothing happened. This is my code:

```
function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{lat}}, {{long}});
      var myOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), myOptions);

      var contentString = '<div id="content">{{name}}<br><span style="font-size:10px;">{{road}}</span><br><span style="font-size:10px;">{{city}} ({{prov}})</span></div>';

      var infowindow_strutt = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          title: '{{name}}'
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow_strutt.open(map,marker);
      });

      var markers = [];
      var markers_strutt = [];
      var markers_concor = [];


      var icon_strutt = {
          url: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/colorful-long-shadow/24/Home-icon.png'
      };


      var icon_concor = {
          url: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/24/home-icon.png'
      };

      var marker_concor
      var marker_strutt
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
          var bounds = map.getBounds();
          var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
          var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
          $.ajax({
              url: '/api/get_marker/',
              cache: false,
              data: {
                   'fromlat': southWest.lat(),
                   'tolat': northEast.lat(),
                   'fromlng': southWest.lng(),
                   'tolng': northEast.lng()
                    },
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
              async: false,
              success: function (data) {
                if (data) {                      
                  $.each(data, function (i, item) {                        
                    if (item.type = 1) {
                      var marker_concor = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
                        icon: icon_concor,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: false
                      });
                    } else if (item.type = 2)  {
                      var marker_strutt = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
                        icon: icon_strutt,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: false
                      });

                      //Create an infoWindow
                      var infowindow_strutt = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                      //set the content of infoWindow (the name)
                      infowindow_strutt.setContent(item.name);

                      //add click listner to marker which will open infoWindow         
                      map.addListener(marker_strutt, 'click', function() {
                          infowindow_strutt.open(marker_strutt); // click on marker opens info window 
                      });
                    }
                    markers_concor.push(marker_concor);
                    markers_strutt.push(marker_strutt);

                    if (marker_strutt) {
                      marker_strutt.setMap(map);
                    }
                     if (marker_concor) {
                      marker_concor.setMap(map);
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
          });              
        }); 
    }


  jQuery(document).ready(function(e) { 

          initialize(); 

       });
```

Where is the issue? Thanks a lot

EDIT: View code

```
def view_get_marker(request):

id = 24

list_id = []
list_marker = []
list_id.append(id)

# type 1 data
A_list = tab_A.objects.filter(id_struttura=id).filter(lat__gt=request.GET.get('fromlat'), lat__lt=request.GET.get('tolat')).filter(lng__gt=request.GET.get('fromlng'), lng__lt=request.GET.get('tolng'))
for a in A_list:          
      list_marker.append([a.lat, a.lng, a.name, a.road, a.city, a.id, 1])
      list_id.append(a.id)

# type 2 data
B_list = list(tab_B.objects.all().values_list('lat','lng','name','road','city','id').exclude(lng__isnull=True).exclude(id__in=lista_id).filter(lat__gt=request.GET.get('fromlat'), lat__lt=request.GET.get('tolat')).filter(lng__gt=request.GET.get('fromlng'), lng__lt=request.GET.get('tolng')))

for lat, lng, name, road, city, id in B_list:
    list_marker.append([lat, lng, name, road, city, id, 2])

if request.is_ajax():
    results = []
    for row in list_marker:
        h_json = {}
        h_json['lat'] = row[0]
        h_json['lng'] = row[1]
        h_json['name'] = unicode(row[2])
        h_json['road'] = unicode(row[3])
        h_json['city'] = unicode(row[4])
        h_json['id'] = row[5]
        h_json['type'] = row[6]
        results.append(h_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

EDIT 2:
I found the solution. The problem was in the event 'click' declaration. The right way is this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_strutt, 'click', (function(marker_strutt, i) {
                      return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent('my content');
                          infowindow.open(map, marker_strutt);
                      }
                      })(marker_strutt, i));
```

In this way I have the popoup!

Comment: Is `/api/get_marker` a custom API that you made in Django? What kind of data does it return?

Comment: Yes is a view. It return json data.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the data? Even better, can you put the code that produces the data in your question?

Comment: I tried your HTML without Django and when I click on the marker an info box pops up. That doesn't happen when you click on your maker? If so, can you put a `console.log` call inside your marker's event listener and see if the event listener is being called?